# Restrict renaming file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to restrict renaming a exported file in vb.net?

Comment: If you mean you created a file and you want to prevent anyone from changing the name of the file on the Windows file system, it is limited to the same rules as any other file. You can change it's attributes, but I don't think you can do anything special to prevent it from being renamed.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry.

I have on hand powerful tools.

There is nothing that can stop me from removing your no-rename restriction from my copy of your own code.

It's a case of last one to move wins and you are by definition not the last one to move.

This thing cannot be done.